вывод типа в variadic templates
Есть рабочий код подсчёта суммы всех аргументов функции через variadic templates. Не могу понять какой возвратный тип используется "под" auto. Через fold expressions было бы удобнее, но очень хочется понять, можно ли задать вместо auto тип и если да, то какой?
#include <iostream>

auto func() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, typename...A>

auto func(T s, A...args) {
    return s + func(args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func(4.9, 1.7, 11, 19.6, 23) << std::endl; // Вывод: 62.2

    return 0;
}

P.S Уважаемый @Harry подсказал, что тип можно вывести посредством std::common_type. Немного подкорректировал. Можно ли считать эти правки корректными? Код компилируется
#include <iostream>

template <typename T = int>
typename std::common_type<T>::type func() {
    return 0;
}

template<typename T, typename...A>

typename std::common_type<T, A...>::type func(T s, A...args) {
    return s + func(args...);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << func(4.9, 1.7, 11, 19.6, 23) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type

Под auto подразумевается тип возвращаемого значения. В вашем случае это скорее всего short или int


какой возвратный тип используется "под" auto

Непонятен ход мыслей. Что не так с auto? (Или с decltype?)
Если вы спрашиваете, есть ли в <type_traits> какой-то шаблон, который выдает возвращаемый тип +, то ответ - нет. И непонятно, зачем он был бы нужен, если можно руками написать decltype.

тип можно вывести посредством std::common_type

Можно, но не для всех типов. Для чисел - работает, а для строк, например - нет. (Хотя для строк и сложение с 0 не работает...)

Через fold expressions было бы удобнее

Тело функции с ними будет выглядеть лучше, но с возвращаемым типом это никак не помогает.

благодарю за размерный ответ! Безусловно, с практической стороны, auto здесь наиболее предпочтительный вариант. Но мне, как новичку, хотелось понять, можно ли его заменить на другой синтаксис в форме шаблона не взирая на "непрактичность" и "запутаность". Про fold expression упомянул специально: к вопросу он не относится никак, но с ним код был бы немного лаконичнее и "новее" с точки зрения современных стандартов С++. А вы не подскажите, как корректно было бы заменить auto на decltype? Пока ещё плохо разбираюсь с ним

@Bizzarro А туда то же самое, что стоит после return: auto func(T s, A...args) -> decltype(s + func(args...)) {return s + func(args...);}. Обратите внимание на синтаксис trailing return type (auto F(...) -> T вместо T F(...)), который не имеет ничего общего с обычным auto, и нужен тут для того, чтобы в decltype можно было упоминать имена параметров (которые иначе в возвращаемом типе упоминать нельзя, потому что они объявляются дальше по коду, чем сам этот возвращаемый тип...).

а когда мы опускаемся на дно рекурсии, достаточно написать auto func()->decltype(0){return 0;}? Это корректная запись?

@Bizzarro Если дно рекурсии с 0 аргументов, то можно просто int func() {return 0;}. Но я бы делал дно с одним аргументом, чтобы, например, поддержать сложение строк (которые с нулем не сложишь).
